# Find $f(x)$ so that $\sum\limits_{cyc}a^{2}-f(x)\left(\prod_{sym}a-\prod_{sym}(1-a)\right)\geqq3(\frac{x}{2})^{2}$ .

Tags: inequality, substitution, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, uvw, muirhead-inequality

> Find $f(x)$ so that
>   $$\sum\limits_{cyc}a^{2}- f(x)\left (\prod\limits_{sym}a- \prod\limits_{sym}(1- a) \right )\geqq 3\left ( \frac{x}{2} \right )^{2}$$

***OP.*** Given three numbers $a, b, c$ so that $\{ a, b, c \}\subseteq [0, x], abc= (x- a)(x- b)(x- c)$. Prove that
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}a^{2}\geqq 3\left ( \frac{x}{2} \right )^{2} \tag{H a i 
 D a n g e l  2 9}$$
For $x= 1\therefore f(1)= 2$
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}a^{2}- 2\left (\prod\limits_{sym}a- \prod\limits_{sym}(1- a) \right )\geqq \frac{3}{4}$$
$$\because (a+ b+ c- 2bc- 1)^{2}+ (2b- 1)^{2}c(1- c)+ \left ( c- \frac{1}{2} \right )^{2}\geqq 0$$

Comment: Don't use `\[ ... \]` in title.  It breaks the flow for no good reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can assume that $\{a,b,c\}\subset(0,X).$

Thus, the condition gives:
$$\frac{X-a}{a}\cdot\frac{X-b}{b}\cdot\frac{X-c}{c}=1.$$
Let $\frac{X-a}{a}=\frac{x}{y}$ and $\frac{X-b}{b}=\frac{y}{z}$, where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are positives.

Thus, $\frac{X-c}{c}=\frac{z}{x}$ and we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{y^2}{(x+y)^2}\geq\frac{3}{4}.$$
Indeed, by C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{y^2}{(x+y)^2}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{y^2(y+z)^2}{(x+y)^2(y+z)^2}\geq\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(y^2+yz)\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(x+y)^2(y+z)^2}.$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that
$$\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(y^2+yz)\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(x+y)^2(y+z)^2}\geq\frac{3}{4}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^4+2x^3y+2x^3z+3x^2y^2-8x^2yz)\geq0,$$ which is true by Muirhead.

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: @HaiDangel I am not sure that it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

You're already on your way to success.

Because the expression

$$ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \geqslant X^2 $$

is a *homogeneous expression*, we can easily do the following substitution:

$$ a'= \cfrac aX ,\, b'= \cfrac bX ,\, c'= \cfrac cX ,\, X'= \cfrac XX = 1 $$

where we can easily find out that:

$$ 0 \leqslant a', b', c' \leqslant X' = 1$$

Can you prove the following inequality on your own?

$$ a'^2 + b'^2 + c'^2 \geqslant \cfrac 34X'^2$$

Can you use the above proof to solve your original question?

Comment: And what is the rest? I think it does not help. If you'll see a down-voting, it's not mine.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg And why is the rest needed? I've already turned the problem into another solved problem (the OP solved it right in their question), so there isn't much more to tell.

Comment: The rest is needed because we need to solve this problem, which you did not make.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let me try! After some transformations we have
$$X< 2\sqrt{\frac{a^2+ b^2+ c^2}{3}}$$
Then $$abc= (X- a)(X- b)(X- c)$$
So assume that
$$a= X- a,\,b= X- b,\,c= X- c$$
Then we have
$$X = 2a = 2b = 2c$$
$$\therefore 4a> 2a< 2\sqrt{\frac{12a^2}{3}}$$
But this only with assumption!

Comment: I think it does not help. If you'll see a down-voting, it's not mine.